# Does anyone want to help me simplify this ugly algebraic expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify
$((2x+3)^4\times\frac{1}{3}\times(3x+5)^{-2/3}\times3) + ((3x+5)^{1/3}\times4\times(2x+3)^3\times2)$

Comment: Please check my edit of your post and correct it if I made any errors. You are more likely to get assistance if you also show us at least what you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 1):

The $\frac 13$ and $3$ in the first term multiply to $1$.  The $2$ and $4$ multiply to what????  Then you can distribute out $(2x+3)^3(2x+5)^{-2/3}$ to make progress.  What have you got then?

Comment: So far i have simplified it down to

Comment: (16x^4+96x^3+216x^2+216x+81) and the rest idk how to simplify

Comment: You lost the factor $(3x+5)^{-2/3}$, which you won't get rid of.  I get $(2x+3)^3(3x+5)^{-2/3}[(2x+3)+8(3x+5)]$.  Now you can expand the square brackets and (if you like) the cubed term.